uploading image in nodejs on cloudinary is not working
I am learning to upload images online using multer and Cloudinary, but for some reason the code stops working on cloudinary.uploader.upload() method. The images are getting stored at desired location and everything is going fine, but it doesn't go ahead that only await part of the function. I am new to this, so I have little idea, and other online resources are mostly useless as of now.
This is my Cloudinary config file
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
});

export default cloudinary;


This is my controller function.
import cloudinary from "../Config/Cloudinary.js";
import path from "path";

export const createbook = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const files = req.files;

    const coverImageMimeType = files.coverImage[0].mimetype.split("/").at(-1);

    const filename = files.coverImage[0].filename;

    const __dirname = path.resolve();

    const filepath = path.join(__dirname, "../public/files/uploads", filename);
    console.log("working");

    const uploadresult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(filepath, {
      folder: "bookcover",
      resource_type: "image",
      public_id: filename,
      format: coverImageMimeType,
    });
    console.log("working");

    console.log("uploadresult", uploadresult);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.json({ message: error.message }).status(500);
  }
};

Basically the second working is not getting printed and code works till only first working print.
Your help as a senior in this is really appreciated. Thank You

You could try logging the different variables to see if they are coming out as expected given the inputs. And there's a possibility you may get more visibility into the issue if you log the response like so:
cloudinary.uploader.upload(filepath, {options}, function(res, err) {
    console.log(err, res);
});

